# Stuck on a probability question (Statistical probability)

Tags: probability, statistics

A national polling company polled Canadians about their coffee consumption and made the following discovery: $85$% of Canadians have at least one cup of coffee a day. Two Canadians are randomly chosen on a randomly chosen day. What is the probability

Part (a) both consume at least one cup of coffee on the chosen day?

Part (b) Refer to the two Canadians chosen in part (a). Find the probability that neither consumes any coffee over the course of the chosen day.

Part (c) Suppose you are to randomly inspect three Canadians on a randomly chosen day. Find the probability that at least two of the three has consumed at least one cup of coffee.

Part (d) Suppose you are to randomly pick $x$-Canadians until the probability that at least one of them has consumed at least one cup of coffee (on the randomly chosen day) is at least $0.96$. How large must $x$ be?

I'm completely lost on this question, would very much appreciate some help.

Comment: In the second line, do you mean "$85\%$ of Canadians"?

Comment: yes, formatting didnt work. @HarryAlli

Comment: @MattyS11 since % is a special character in Latex (indicating a comment), you need to do \% if you want it to appear in mathjax (though just putting it outside the $'s like you did here works too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question isn't clear about the distinction between "random day" and "every day" is, assume $85%$ drink coffee and $15%$ don't.

a) Given two Canadians $A,B$, assume the events $A$ drinks coffee and $B$ drinks coffee are independent. So the answer is $.85*.85$.

b) By same logic, $.15*.15$.

c) The probability that all three drink coffee is $.85^3$. The probability that two drink and the third doesn't is $.85^2*.15$, however there are 3 ways this can happen (pick one of three to not drink) so multiply this by 3. The answer is $.85^3+3(.85^2\cdot0.15)$

d) Find the opposite: what's the probability that of $n$ people, all $n$ of them don't drink coffee?

Comment: Do you mean that I should find the probability that exactly none drink coffee on any given day?

Comment: Yeah since that's $1-$ P(someone drinks coffee)

Comment: I'm not sure how to begin the calculation. I'm basing all of my logic by having a set amount of people in the sample space to begin with.

Comment: It's tough to do that (drawing without replacement) without knowing how many people are in the sample space. In the case where the number of people is large (36 milllion) you can just assume each person drawn has a constant $0.85$ chance to drink coffee.

Comment: turns out the answer was 2! I guess that makes sense. Thanks for the help

Comment: NP! didn't want to spoil too much ;)